# Generic types java

Tags: java, android, generics, methods

Check my Custom class. If I change DoSomething() to

```
 final Custom<User> _custom = new Custom<>(new TypeToken<Custom<User>.Response<User>>(){}, "");
```

Then the DEBUG log is: `"com.application.models.Custom$Response<com.application.models.User>" serverResponse: ""`

But if DoSomething is:

```
  final Custom<T> _custom = new Custom<>(new TypeToken<Custom<T>.Response<T>>(){}, "");
```

The DEBUG log is:

```
"com.application.models.Custom$Response<T>" serverResponse: "
```

I have a class like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static <T> void DoSomething()
    {
        final Custom<T> _custom = new Custom<>(new TypeToken<Custom<T>.Response<T>>(){}, "");
    }
}
```

// I added the debug log at the right of the variables

```
public class Custom<T>
{
    private TypeToken<Response<T>> _responseType;   _response: null
    private Response<T> _response; _response: null
    private String _serverResponse; _serverResponse = null;

    public Custom(TypeToken<Response<T>> responseType, String serverResponse)  `responseType: "com.application.models.Custom$Response<T>" serverResponse: "`
    {
        this._responseType = responseType;
        this._serverResponse = serverResponse;
    }

     public class Response<t>
    {
        private List<t> data = null;

        public List<t> GetData()
        {
            return this.data;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I call Main..

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id;

    public void Test()
    {
        Main.<User>DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *for some reason when I compile the T still generic when I create Custom*?

Comment: I'm assuming `Main<User> main = new User<>();` is a typo and should be `Main<User> main = new Main<>();`, right?.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer

Comment: I don't see any problem (except for the missing `class` keyword in `User` class and the missing return type in `IOnSuccess(List<User> list)`. Oh, and you might want to change `new ArrayList()` to `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Is weird, I keep getting com.application.testing.Custom<T > If I use the "T" from Main in Custom<T >

Comment: @DexSebas, could you explain what you mean with your logs getting a `T` ? T should not exist at Runtime. Where are there from ? This works fine for me. Had the same diff than Eran, I rewrite it quickly and printed the list content in the Interface, this works fine.

Comment: I updated my question* now.

Comment: Well, not sure what is your problem here, I see `com.application.models.Custom$Response<com.application.models.User` on the line using the generic T so ... what are you asking again ?

Comment: No, Im sorry.. I edited the answer, in that line I get < T >

Comment: With the debugger maybe but check the type of a "T instance", you wil see that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Java mostly work with compile time generics, meaning that when you compile then your generics are gone. They are only a compile time check. Does that answer your question? Google Type Erasure.

Comment: So I cant use `final Custom<T> _custom = new Custom<>(model); ` ?

Comment: That syntax will not work unless T is a declared class. The abstraction of generics can be used when defining a class or method. When instantiating a class you will either specify type or use type inference to deduce the type.

Comment: I wrote declared class and I do not see a "class T{.....". new Custom<>(model) will instantiate a Custom<TheTypeOfModel>. Custom<T> cannot be assigned to that.